# Get cursor position in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4

I cannot find `selectionStart` in Ionic 4 when I am referencing `ion-textarea`. In Ionic v3 I did something like this to get cursor position:

for iOS `textArea._native.nativeElement.selectionStart` 
and for Android `event.target.selectionStart`

but it seems like I cannot find selectionStart on elementRef.

I tried to access element using

`@ViewChild('txArea', { read: ElementRef }) textArea: ElementRef;`

and

```
<ion-textarea
    #txArea
    [(ngModel)]="description"
    (keyup)="onKeyUp($event, txArea)"
    rows="4"
    autocorrect="on" autocomplete="on"
    placeholder="Enter description (i.e. @JoeDoe, #forehand)">
</ion-textarea>
```

Can somebody help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

```
MouseEvent.clientX
MouseEvent.clientY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector() on the nativeElement.

Assume that you are trying to access the view child reference using an instance variable as follows:

```
@ViewChild('txArea', {static: false, read: ElementRef})
txArea: ElementRef;
```

You can get selectionStart from an event handler (class method) as follows:

```
    onClick () {

      console.log(
           this
           .txArea
           .nativeElement
           .querySelector('textarea')
           .selectionStart
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the real input in Ionic

```js
onKeyUp($event, txArea){
   const realInput = $event.target.querySelector('input')
   const start = realInput.selectionStart;
   const end = realInput.selectionEnd;
}
```

this way you can get selectionStart and selectionEnd